# How to mount a VOLUME with Dockerfile for the Linux /sys?

Tags: docker

I need to mount a volume for the /sys to make that piece read-write to adjust the transparent pages to run TokuDB.

I must have that magic done within a Dockerfile, and using VOLUME will give me an empty /sys. I need to have a way to mount a volume under the OS files added by default to /sys.

With a docker run command, I can do it as below:

```
docker run -it \
  --volume=/sys:/sys:rw \
ubuntu:latest
```

My question is, how can I do it using the Dockerfile?

Thanks, folks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The setting you're trying to change is a kernel-level setting, that will affect all other containers and all other non-container processes on the host.  That means Docker will generally prevent a container from changing it at all.  An image also can't grant itself permission to make changes to the host system; you can't ever specify a host directory in a Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive.

I would not try to make this change in your container.  Use `sysctl` on the host system as root.  You should be able to include a startup-time check and warn if the value isn't set correctly, and this would also be a good thing to document in your source repository's `README.md` file.

Comment: Ok. I was kinda expecting that answer as I am not finding anything related to creating an underlying volume mounted at /sys and having the OS create its metadata files over that volume. The case is that, if I don't add a --volume ... like the one I added on the description, the rootfs will be read-only for the changes I need to execute for transparent pages. That's why I need a volume and need that volume to be rw. I'm still researching it, but, with documenting the README for when scheduling the container in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I geuss you want to copy, so in the dockerfile add:

```
COPY /sys /sys
```

To copy it from your host into the container.

Comment: `/sys` isn't a "real" filesystem so you can't copy the files out of it; and in any case you can't `COPY` files from outside the `docker build` context directory.